# Share GPU memory for different users in keras and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, theano-cuda

We had only one GPU installed with CUDA drivers and whenever one user runs the code, the whole memory is assigned to that user. And the other users are unable to use the GPU. Is there a way to get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `keras`, add this at the beginning of your script:

```
from keras import backend as K

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(sess)
```

This will prevent `tensorflow` to take all the memory as can be seen [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6031).

If you are using `tensorflow` without `keras`, add this:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

As shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how to limit GPU with only running tensorflow (the code written in tensorflow only), without any environment of keras.

Comment: @Rajesh I modified my answer according to your needs

Comment: @vinzee  What if I don't use `tf.Session` ? Because `tf2.1` allows us to make trians directly with `tf.Keras.Models.Compile`